# Read a line and store as variable

Tags: arrays, batch-file

**Background:**

Just need some assistance with a batch file that is meant to read (by line) a text file (it's an error log).  Each line has a file path of files that have not been backed up.  I need to read these paths into their own variable of sorts so I can copy them manually using this batch (running robocopy or xcopy or something).

**Assistance:**

I would like some help with trying to find the string starting with "\\" and saving everything that follows into an array which is then passed to some "functions" that do the checking and copying.

**Current progress:**

I can at the moment do the following:

- Read the file
- Make checks on the variable to ensure it's not already part of a manual copy process
- Copy the data

**Code:**

This is where I am stuck. Reading the file into `%%a` and trying to now read `%%a` into a variable to check the string for "\\" and then copying that+the_rest_of_the_line into the variable I would ultimately do the checking and copying from.

```
set LOGPATH=C:\logs\
echo finding path
cd %LOGPATH%
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (err.log) do (
)
pause
```

I have tried to use `findstr` but I can't see how it works becuase it keeps delimiting at a singular "\"

Also here's a sample of the log:

> 18:34:55  Cannot open \\server\path\file

Comment: `find "\\"` will give you the lines you need.  The actual process needs to explained, along with the data, to give any useful info - if you need further help.

Comment: I thought I did explain the process?  I need to read a file, retrieve all the file paths based on the log - store the paths as a variable - pass the variable to an exclusion list and make sure it's not part of this list then use the path to copy the data. However, I only need the retrieval of the path everything else is done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated content base on the file format:

Try this command:

```
for /f "tokens=2* delims=\" %%a in (test.txt) do (
    @echo \\%%a\%%b
)
```

to see if it output the path correctly. This is assume the path is the last item in the line.

Comment: Thanks, problem is that the line does not start with "\\" it's in the middle of it after the date/time stamp and "Cannot open" so I am getting a line with `18:34:55 Cannot open \\server\path\file`

Comment: Mate. Legend! Works like a charm